# Should I use an article in “extract text from document” phrases?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, countability

I am writing an article about the extraction of an entire text from a document. I am not sure if I should use "a", "the", or nothing in "extract text" phrases.

Sample sentences:

1. "How to extract text from non-searchable PDF."
2. "You need to perform OCR to extract text from non-searchable PDF documents."
3. "For searchable PDFs, you can extract text without recognition."

Here I mean the extraction of all text in the document. I.e. we cannot extract 2 different texts from the document. And I do not mean that we need to extract some specific text. We just need all document's text.

Am I right that "text" is uncountable in samples 1-3 and does not require an article?

4. "You can extract a text manually. Open a document, then select and copy some text."

Am I right that "text" is countable here and requires "a" article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's uncountable in all four. No article needed.